# Where does spacy language model download?

Tags: python, spacy

I have a simple command:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web
```

And I cannot for the life of me figure out where it downloads. I search for "en_core_web" but can find absolutely nothing, anywhere. And I can't for the life of me figure out what to search to understand the syntax behind this command.

What do you even call this line? A python command line argument? I couldn't find what to search for to specify a download location.

Please help!

Answer (score 23):

I stumbled across the same question and the model path can be found using the model class variable to a loaded spacy model.

For instance, having completed the model download at the command line as follows:
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

then within the python shell:

```
import spacy
model = spacy. load("en_core_web_sm")
model._path
```

This will show you where the model has been installed in your system.

If you want to download to a different location, I believe you can write the following at the command line:
`python -m spacy.en.download en_core_web_sm --data-path /some/dir`

Hope that helps

Comment: it is `model.path` in spacy 3

Comment: `no such option: --data-path`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.6 and both `model.path` and `model._path` work for me

Answer (score 11):

I can't seem to find any evidence that spacy pays attention to the `$SPACY_DATA_DIR` environment variable, nor can I get the above `--data-path` or `model.path` (`--model.path`?) parameters to work when trying to download models to a particular place. For me this was an issue as I was trying to keep the models out of a Docker image so that they could be persisted or be updated easily without rebuilding the image.

I *eventually* came to the following solution for using pre-trained models:

1. Run the download code as normal (i.e. `python -m spacy.download en_core_web_lg`)
2. In Python: `import spacy` and then `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')`
3. Now save this to the place you want it: `nlp.to_disk('path/to/dir')`

You can now load this from the local file via `nlp=spacy.load('path/to/dir')`. There's a suggestion in the documentation that you can download the models manually:

> You can place the model data directory anywhere on your local file system. To use it with spaCy, simply assign it a name by creating a shortcut link for the data directory.
> But I can't make sense of what this means in practice (have submitted an 'issue' to spaCy).

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 7):

Putting all together the solutions proposed above, to control `spacy` download location, the following approach is possibile:

```
cache_dir=os.getenv("cache_dir", "../../models")
model_path="en_core_web_sm"
try:
    nlp = spacy.load(os.path.join(cache_dir,model_path))
except OSError:
    spacy.cli.download(model_path)
    nlp = spacy.load(model_path)
    nlp.to_disk(os.path.join(cache_dir,model_path))
```

In this way, starting from the second execution, the model will be available under requested location

```
nlp = spacy.load(os.path.join(cache_dir,model_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

After having an issue with finding the download directory what I found was that at least on Linux the initial download before being installed to the python library seems to controlled by pip and the `python -m spacy.download ...` command takes pip options.
So `--cache-dir <dir>` changes the download location and in my case the `--no-cache-dir` fixed my lack of space in the default download location issue. I believe the actual installed location will be with your python libraries where ever those are depending on distribution and virtual environments and the such.