# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ''

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, spacy, fedora

I am trying to download the "en_core_web_lg" using `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`,on Fedora remix for WSL. but I get the error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ''`. Hope someone help with it. Here is the full traceback of the error

```
$ python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 87, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typer/core.py", line 785, in main
    **extra,
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typer/core.py", line 216, in _main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 43, in download_cli
    download(model, direct, sdist, *ctx.args)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 82, in download
    download_model(filename, pip_args)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/cli/download.py", line 159, in download_model
    run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 1015, in run_command
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT if capture else None,
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/time/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ''
```

System Environments:
Python 3.7.6
Fedora Remix on WSL Generic release 38 (Generic)
conda 4.12.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I facing PermissionError while installing SpaCy en\_core\_web\_sm on SSH server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919242/why-am-i-facing-permissionerror-while-installing-spacy-en-core-web-sm-on-ssh-ser)

Comment: @nofinator Nope I get the same error. And of course I changed with 'user' with the username